# The frog puzzle

Tags: probability, intuition, puzzle

So here's the puzzle. You're poisoned in the jungle and the only way to save yourself is to lick a special kind of frog. To make matters worse, only the female of that species will do. Licking the male frog doesn't do anything.
The male and female frogs look identical. The only difference is that the male frog makes a sound and the female is silent.

So you run through the jungle and spot a frog in front of you. Before you could start running towards it you hear a sound behind you. You turn around and spot two frogs there. There's only time to run to one side.

Now, the best course of action is to run towards the two frogs and lick both. The reasoning is that there are 4 possible combinations of two frogs and knowing that one of them is male eliminates only one of those possibilities. Of the remaining three, two of them have at least one female frog. This gives you a $\frac 2 3$ chance of survival as opposed to a $\frac 1 2$ with the single frog.

Now here's my problem. The reason this works is because you don't know which frog made the sound. If you did, you'd have a $50\%$ chance with the other one. But wouldn't that imply that, if you for some reason turned around earlier to see which one made the sound, you would decrease your chances of survival? What's the explanation here?

Comment: (Note that your calculation of the $\frac23$ assumes that the two frogs' sexes are independent of each other, which may or may not be accurate....)

Comment: @GregMartin On one hand I'd say that we can assume independence here, on the other hand, it's assumptions like these that often break intuition.

Comment: You're right that hearing a frog sound removes one of the possibilities, but it doesn't mean the other three possibilities are now equally likely. There are $2^3=8$ possible events, based on: which frog makes the sound; sex of first frog; sex of second frog. $4$ of these events have a female frog making the sound, which is ruled out. Of the remaining $4$ events, two of them have two male frogs.

Comment: @GregMartin If the initial four combinations are equally likely, then removing one leaves three equally likely possibilities.

Comment: [The only difference is that the male frog makes a sound and the female is silent.] It's usually the reverse. // How are you modeling the sound making? What is the underlying process? If making a noise makes a frog male, then not making noise over time increases likelihood of it being a female. The chances for the group of 2 frogs are not 2/3 since the fact that you heard the noise from the back puts extra weight on male/male possibility as you are approximately twice as likely to hear from a pair of males than from one

Comment: @A.S. I'm not sure what you're asking here. This is a hypothetical, theoretical scenario.

Comment: Well, you have to model the cause of the sound to understand what does it actually mean. Imagine a situation where a male in the presense of a female ALWAYS make a noise or the opposite - never makes a noise. This would affect your decision deeply. Could you have heard two male sounds if there were 2 males?

Comment: @A.S. Over time.  One second is not over time.  The probability that a frog is female because it didn't croak in the one second you watched it can be assume to be insignificant.  At any rate, all this stuff about males gathering in groups and silence increasing probability is besides the point.  This is a theoretical question about whether information *lowers* probability.  We should address that.  You know a 1/2 occurence happened to one unknown member of a group of 2.  Does it make sense that knowing which one did the occurence lowers your chances?

Comment: @A.S.  As this is hypothetical I am delaring that in NOT the situation.  A male frog might croak one time in its lifetime or it may choose never to croak ever.  Presence of female has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well, I don't like jumping to the simplest probability model given a vague problem statement and find it interesting to introduce more complex models. If the situation was the following - you have a radar gun that can tell you the presence of a male frog in a group of frogs - no licking involved. You point this "gun" at a pair of frogs and it comes back "yes". Then there is 2/3 chance that one of those frogs is female. If you point this gun at a single frog (rather than a group) and it rings yes, there is 1/2 chance that one of the frogs is female.

Comment: @A.S. The problem statement really wasn't that vague. I take slight offense to that. Any kind of story-based statement of a problem is inherently open to nit picks. Picking the most obvious model is assumed.

Comment: The statement IS vague as probability problems are quite sensitive to formulation and interpretation. I almost immediately thought of a male frog emitting a sound at some low intensity $Poisson(\lambda)$. Then probability of hearing a sound in time $t$ given MF is $e^{-\lambda t}\lambda t$ and given MM is $e^{-2\lambda t}2\lambda t$. MF:MM a priori odds are 2:1, so odds after hearing a sound are $e^{\lambda t}:1$. In the other direction, F:M odds are $e^{\lambda t}:1$ too - so you are indifferent. Same if you know exactly which frog made a sound. Did you mean my "radar gun" interpretation?

Comment: @A.S. Well, the radar interpretation kind of masks the problem since it requires you to pick one frog to point at. To stay true to the problem we could say that it seems odd that upgrading the radar gun so it can tell you WHICH frog is male out of two of them somehow seems to decrease your odds of survival.

Comment: What would the radar gun tell you if you pointed it as two male frogs?

Comment: @A.S. I guess it would pick one of two at random and say that one is male.

Comment: Then the upgraded gun will give you the same 2:1 odds, This is exactly why it is so important to formalize your story-based physical process. Alternative formalizations are half the fun. The only way to know which frog made a sound is to probe that particular frog - there is no other way.

Comment: Is your question basically a classical one: "One of my 2 children is a boy" vs "My firstborn is a boy"?

Comment: @fleablood You are jumping to conclusions based on an already existing set of "theoretical questions". I prefer to model a story as given (frogs making sounds is a random process) while maintaining simplicity and tractability. If the OP had a specific theoretical question mind, he should have used a different, more fitting, story or avoid a story all-together. Otherwise the question is - is it possible that $P(A|B)\ne P(A|C)$? Of course. As the first realistic approximation, though, just hearing one frog keeps you indifferent between the front and the back as shown above.

Comment: This is a *math* problem.  Not a trick question puzzle to avoid math.  You have a situation.  You have three frogs each with 1/2 probability of being male.  You know that one of two of them is male.  What is the probability that it is the only male of the bunch.  It's a straightforward question.  Making up stories about detection gu s and speculative biology is making up information that isn't there and isn't appropriate.  You're wasting time to avoid math.

Comment: @flea This is not a math problem per se as there are no frogs in math. This is a *story* to be *modeled* as a probability question. "You know that one of two of them is male" is highly unspecified because the process that yielded this knowledge matters. A LOT. I answered this straightforward question assuming a very reasonable process. You are under false impression that questions come from a limited bank of theoretical questions you have already encountered and are able to match to a new story. You must think that $x^2+1=0$ has no solutions because, well, it's straightforward that $x^2\ge 0$.

Answer (score 18):

In the two-frog scenario, the event "One croak was heard" is *not* the same as the event "at least one frog is male".

There are eight possibilities: the "left" frog can be female or male, the "right" frog can be female or male, and exactly one croak was emitted or not.  Assuming males croak with probability $p$ while you are in their presence, and everything is independent, the following table enumerates the eight possibilities and their probabilities:
$$
\begin{array}{c|l|c|c|c|c}
\text{Outcome} & \text{Probability} &\text{One croak?}&\text{F present?}&\text{At least one M?}\\
\hline
FF0 & \frac14 & & Y&\\ 
FF1 &0&Y&Y&\\
FM0 &\frac14(1-p) &&Y&Y\\
FM1&\frac14p&Y&Y&Y\\
MF0&\frac14(1-p)&&Y&Y\\
MF1&\frac14p&Y&Y&Y\\
MM0&\frac14(p^2+(1-p)^2)&&&Y\\
MM1&\frac14\cdot 2p(1-p)&Y&&Y\\
\end{array}
$$
Using the above table, the probability that you survive given you heard a croak is
$$
P(\text{F present}\mid\text{one croak})=\frac{P(FF1,FM1,MF1)}{P(FF1,FM1,MF1,MM1)}=\frac{0+\frac14p+\frac14p}{0+\frac14p+\frac14p+\frac142p(1-p)}=\frac1{2-p}.
$$
This makes intuitive sense, because if males croak all the time ($p=1$), then for sure the other frog is female; if males croak but very rarely, then it's a coin toss whether the other frog is female. Note that the above probability is never smaller than $\frac12$, so the two-frog lick is always a better strategy than the one-frog lick.

Using the above table, the probability $P(\text{survive}\mid\text{at least one M})$ is properly calculated as $2/3$, but this result is neither here nor there, because *you didn't observe that event*.

As for your other question, we can modify the outcome space to specify whether the left frog croaked or the right one. Using a similar enumeration to the above, the prob that you survive given you heard a croak from only the left frog is:
$$P(\text{F present}\mid\text{only left frog croaked})
={P(M1F0)\over P(M1F0,M1M0)}={\frac12p\cdot\frac121\over\frac12p\cdot\frac121+\frac12p\cdot\frac12(1-p)}=\frac1{2-p},
$$
exactly the same probability as when you didn't know which frog croaked. The probability of survival given that only the right frog croaked is the same. Conclusion: knowledge of *which* frog croaked does not lower your probability of survival.

Comment: This is what I got as well under similar model. The final probability is also equal to the probability that the frog in front is $F$ making you indifferent between 1 frog no croaks and 2 frogs one croak.

Comment: @A.S. Great observation. The conditional probability that a frog is female given that you have not heard it croak is $P(F0)/P(F0,M0)=(\frac12\cdot1)/(\frac12\cdot1+\frac12\cdot(1-p))=1/(2-p)$.

Comment: This is always the best approach to probability questions that have seemingly non-intuitive features in them. As your last equation shows, once we know which frog did croak, probability that other frog is female is higher than that it is a male; because we're looking for not just any male frog but a _non-croaked_ male frog, which has less probability than former one. This is part-reason why turning back earlier and see the frog that makes the sound didn't affect our chance of survival.

Comment: I think this is approaching the problem at the wrong time. A frog croaked, you turned around and now you're calculating your current chances of survival.

Comment: @Luka you are ignoring the PROCESS that leads to croaks. In the Monty Hall, only 1 door is eliminated, but it matters whether or not you picked a door (that can't be eliminated) before the elimination. An open door doesn't just mean "no goat behind it" and similarly a croak doesn't  just mean "at least one male" as a croak is more likely to come from MM as opposed to MF.

Comment: @A.S. This is all irrelevant. You can imagine that another person behind you pointed at one male frog and said that it's male. You just didn't see which one he pointed at. There's no process. This just happened and this is your universe. If both were male he'd pick one at random. You can run the odds and see that without knowing which one he pointed at there's a 2/3 chance, and with knowing the extra info there's a 1/2 chance.

Comment: That person has to first NOTICE that pair and he is MORE likely to notice MM as opposed to MF - because he pays attention to ONE frog at a time and notices MALES. You are not sampling PAIRS of frogs - you are sampling SPECIFIC FROGS out of a pair and a MM is more likely to produce a M as opposed to MF. You keep on SWITCHING a situation/process and insisting it's the SAME process. MM is more likely to produce a single croak than MF in the same time period. Period.

Comment: @A.S. Why do you insist that there has to be some method by which the information is acquired? The guy just KNOWS the gender of the frogs. He points at a male one. If both are male, he points at one at random. If both are male HE KNOWS both are male. It doesn't take him any more or less time and it certainly doesn't affect anything else in the universe. He just decides to point at one of them at random. A 50-50 chance.

Comment: This is a process different from frogs crocking and I already addressed in the comments for OP. You can't speak of probabilities until you DEFINE/formalize/clarify the process of how information was acquired. "Just known" doesn't cut it. I just KNOW that the second frog is female. Trust me. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: @A.S. While certainly not satisfying, I guess I can appreciate what you're saying.

Comment: @Luka In simplest terms: if you randomly sample *families* with 2 children, ask a question: "is at least one kid male?" and get an affirmative, then chances of the other being a girl are $2/3$. If you, on the other hand, randomly sample *children* from 2-children families and that child is a male, then chances of his subling being a girl are $1/2$. In both cases, you just KNOW that one of the kids in the family is a guy, but information comes to you from different processes. Same with Monte Hall.

Comment: @LukaHorvat, since the main problem is that decrease of survival chance is non-intuitive, you have to give us more why you think that decrease is non-intuitive to understand and help you. Because this is pretty intuitive to me. In your scenario in second comment, you give one reason which is "extra-info". Why is extra-info does not decrease chance of survival? There is no feature in this info that implying non-decrease of survival's chance. This person as well says "Both frogs are male!" (just before licking) once you reach the frogs and decrease your chance to 0. How is this extra-info helps?

Comment: @LukaHorvat, let me give you intuitive explanation in your no-croaking scenario: You turn back and see two frogs and immediately know your chance is 75%. Intrusive person came and shouts "At least one frog is male!", and you immediately know your chance is decreased, because now you know both of them can't be female. After that, person says "Left one is male!", and now you know that left one is can't be female, therefore decreasing your chance more.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two ways of looking at this question, which can lead to different answers and has led to discussions that mix the two different viewpoints:

1. The view as in [grand_chat's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683796/152692) where the premise is "You are in a forest with one frog left, two frogs right" and the question "Given that you hear a croak on the right, what is the chance that you survive if you lick the frogs on the right". Here, the probability of croaking plays an essential role in the probability determination.
2. The view  that takes all information in the question as a given, where the premise is  "You are in a forest with one frog left, two frogs right, and you have heard a croak on the right" and the question is "What is the chance that you survive if you lick the frogs on the right?". Here, the croaking is a given and does not play a role in the probability determination; it is equivalent to the given of 'there is a male on the right'.

In a physicists language, the ensembles that are considered are different: view 1 has the ensemble of all systems with a frog left and two frogs right with the question of the correlation between a measurement of a croak on the right with finding a female on the right; view 2 has the ensemble of all systems with a frog on the left and a two frogs on the right, at least one of which is male, with the question of the probability of a female on the right.

View 1 is more closely related to the real world, but it does require some assumptions/knowledge about the croak probability distributions, and is explained well in [grand_chat's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683796/152692). View 2 is more abstract and probably more in line with the intent of the 'puzzle', where no knowledge of croaking probabilities is needed.

---

Now to answer your question in view 2, by knowing *which* frog croaked, you are filtering your ensemble, which is populated by 'MM', 'MF', and 'FM' pairs, to the new ensemble where there are only 'MM' and 'MF' pairs (assuming the left of the pair is the male). So, the knowledge of knowing the position of the male filters away the also favourable situation of 'FM', therefore your chance inside this ensemble (this premise) is reduced with respect to the original.

Answer (score 2):

Why is this a problem to you?

Suppose you had a lottery with 4 people.  There are 3 blue pieces of paper and 1 red.  Whoever draws the red will be killed.  You figure your chances of surviving are 3 in 4.  Person A (not you) is called forward and draws a paper.  It's blue.  So now you figure your chances of surviving have dropped to 2 in 3.  How does knowing something lower your chances?  Well, because it eliminates possibilities.

So why is this a problem with the frogs?

There are 8 possibilities for the gender of 3 frogs.

MM|M Back: BAD, Front BAD

MM|F Back: BAD, Front GOOD

MF|M Back: GOOD, Front BAD

MF|F Back: GOOD, Front GOOD

FM|M Back: GOOD, Front BAD

FM|F Back: GOOD, Front GOOD

FF|M Back: GOOD, Front BAD

FF|F Back: GOOD, Front GOOD

So if you lick the front your chances of surviving are 4/8 = 1/2.  If you lick the back your chances are 3/4.

If you hear a croak you eliminate 2 possibilities and are left with:

MM|M Back: BAD, Front BAD

MM|F Back: BAD, Front GOOD

MF|M Back: GOOD, Front BAD

MF|F Back: GOOD, Front GOOD

FM|M Back: GOOD, Front BAD

FM|F Back: GOOD, Front GOOD

FF|M Back: IMPOSSIBLE

FF|F Back: IMPOSSIBLE

Licking the front gives your chances at 3/6 = 1/2.  Licking the back gives your chances at 4/6 = 2/3.

If you turn and see the first frog croak you've eliminated 4 possibilities and are left with:

MM|M Back: BAD, Front BAD

MM|F Back: BAD, Front GOOD

MF|M Back: GOOD, Front BAD

MF|F Back: GOOD, Front GOOD

FM|M IMPOSSIBLE

FM|F Back: IMPOSSIBLE

FF|M Back: IMPOSSIBLE

FF|F Back: IMPOSSIBLE

Now either you lick the back and your chances are 2/4 =1/2 or you lick the front and your chances are 2/4 = 1/2.

Comment: If I had a $1/4$ chance of survival and now I have a $1/3$ then surely my chances haven't dropped but increased.

Comment: Your chance of *dying* have increased.  Your chance of survive was 3/4  Now it's only 2/3.

Comment: Right. I still don't think this is a valid argument. A person picking a ticket removes it from the pool and alters the system. The frogs don't change gender and my turning around certainly doesn't either.

Comment: In other words. If I knew that the first ticket was blue, it would only serve to benefit me since I could pick it. Yes, seeing that the ticket it blue adds information that would benefit me, but removing a ticket from the pool has a much worse effect.

Comment: I agree it doesn't feel right but I think it actually is correct.  I don't think it's a Monty hall issue.

Comment: If we eliminate the extraneous information this is simply the "mr. B had two children, one of them is a boy; what is the probability the other is a boy".  It's well established the probability is only 1/3.

Comment: I don't understand why MF, and FM are two separate events, given that we know one is a male. You're treating the male frog as though it's a random event when in reality he is certainly male, so there's no probability there. Let's say there's 100,000 frogs behind you, and 99,999 croaked. By this logic it's nearly certain that by licking the frogs behind you will yield success, yet obviously adding more male frogs don't actually improve your odds.

Comment: We don't know which one was the male. We only know there is at least one male. There are three equally likely ways that could occur. Two have female frogs. If you hear 99,999 croaks there are 100,001 thousand equally likely ways this could occur. 100,000 involve females. It **is** a near certainty that if you hear 99,999 croaks there's a female. That *isn't* faulty reasoning. There is only one way the remaining frog can be male but there are 100,000 ways it can be female.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me see the error in my logic.

Comment: @fleablood Your reasoning is not even wrong. 99,999 crocks can come from 100,000 male frogs in exactly 100,000 equally likely ways. And there are also 100,000 ways to pick one female out of 100,000. Surprise - hearing 99,999 crocks out of 100,000 frogs gives you the same chances for a female as hearing 0 crocks from 1 frog - just as normal logic/reasoning suggests. What a bummer it must be for you that hearing crocks from frogs is a different process from a father volunteering information about his family. But of course you know the answer in advance because it's a *theoretical math problem*.

Comment: I guess the main problem (which this answer does point out) is the interpretation of what "chances of survival" actually means. It's not tied to the actual situation but the information you have about it. It kind of helps to also consider that if I closed my ears I'd think my odds were even higher.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 50% regardless of if you know which frog croaked. If you don't know which frog croaked, then we must consider that the state MM has a multiplicity of 2, ie it is twice as likely as either MF or FM, because there are two ways that this result can exist. It will be more clear if we assign the croaking frog its own notation. Lets call the croaking frog Mc, this gives the states: McM, MMc, FMc, and McF, which are all equally as likely, and of which 50% contain a female.

This problem is equivalent to having a friend flip 2 coins behind your back and telling you that at least coin has come up heads, clearly the probability of the second coin being heads as well is 50%, as if it is the only coin flipped. If your friend shows you one of the coins and it is heads, this changes nothing about the probability of the other coins state.

Answer (score 0):

The riddle restriction that you do not know which frog has crocked is unnecessary and misleading.

Even if you had seen clearly that it was the left frog that crocked. The chances of the right frog to be a female would be 67%!.
How can it be? …. Because at a MM situation the chances that the left frog will crock are only ½ of the chance (100%) it will crock at a MF situation.
So if the left frog has crock. It is twice as probable that its partner is a female.

To show it clearly, lest make a additional arbitrary rule:
When 2 males are sitting together, the older frog will crock and the young will stay silent.
Now we have 6 possible scenarios.
M-old-crock / F-young
M-young-crock / F-old
F-young / M-old-Crock
F-old / M-young-crock
M-old-Crock / M-young
M-young / M-old-Crock

If the left frog had crocked then it have equal probability to be:
M-old-crock / F-young
M-young-crock / F-old
M-old-Crock / M-young

And 2/3rd of the possibilities involve the 2nd frog to be a female.