# The three-coin-flip riddle

Tags: statistics, puzzle, fake-proofs, paradoxes

Is the following true (It seems obvious to me that it's not... but... a PhD in physics, *Derek Abbott*, seems to think others *explanation at end of post*):

**Someone flips 3 coins on the table, they are then covered with paper so I can't see. Two of the coins are on the left of the table, one coin is on the right of the table. I go to the left of the table and start to slide the paper back slowly, eventually revealing the first of the two coins, if it's tails I just have the person re-flip, but if it's heads then I predict the other coin is tails and continue pulling the paper back to reveal tails 66% of the time.**

---

Ted-ed *(a TED talks division)* published a video recently via Physics PHD *Derek Abbott* called "The Frog Riddle" - you can watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpwSGsb-rTs and now I'm very confused, please tell me their video is just wrong.

I don't understand mathematically how they are arriving at their conclusion. If this were any other youtube video in my feed I would just wave it off as erroneous, but TED is a very large and very famous organization with lots of editors and is also notoriously intellectual. Also I was having a hard time finding many who disagreed in the youtube comments.

Comment: You should stop drinking TED-flavoured Kool-aid and look up a thread on reddit (or here) that explains why the video's reasoning is wrong. In a nutshell, $MM$ is more likely (x2) to produce a crock as a opposed to $MF$ and that makes chances the same as 1 frog and zero crocks.

Comment: @A.S. +1, Sorry it's just that he is a PhD in physics so I assume I am wrong (as I did not even go to college (pursued business) haha). Just wanted to get multiple opinions with the scenario I posed.

Comment: As with the Monty-Hall paradox, there is a simple way to cast out any doubt: build the tree of possible outcomes, and count the number of branches.

Comment: See https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/48br02/is_tededs_explanation_of_their_frog_riddle_wrong/d0km7is and my answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683658/the-frog-puzzle/1683697#comment3436248_1683658 (see other comments as well). If you assume $\lambda t$ small, you'll  get 1:1 odds of a female.

Comment: @Graffitics but the monty hall problem relies on a guaranteed pre-set of 2 goats and 1 car, and also the pre-knowledge (by the hose) of which doors contain which objects.

Comment: Well, it's time to stop trusting Physics/Econ PhD's (look at LTCM) and brand-names such as TED. Conditioning is tricky to the point that many mathematicians get Monty Hall wrong on the first few tries.

Comment: Ok, what's *LTCM*?

Comment: Scratch that @A.S. I remember reading about this! (Wasn't alive back then). I did think their formulas worked however, it's just when you have loss day after day after day with overhead increasing it is possible for risked wealth to go over-unity. They just weren't expecting extreme loss for that many days in a row.

Comment: You can still write down all possibilities, it's boring but it works, and you don't have to rely on 'reasonings'.

Comment: This just seems like gamblers fallacy though... @Graffitics

Comment: No. The gambler's fallacy is the confusion between the expectation between of $n+1$ events and the expectation of the $n+1$ event *knowing the first $n$ events*. If you write down the complete tree of outcomes, then there's no gambler's fallacy: even if you failed the first $n$ coin tosses, you can read that you still have probability $1/2$ that you're going to win the next one.

Answer (score 0):

The coin scenario you describe differs from the frog scenario in the video in that you peek at a particular one of the coins and try to predict the other coin on that basis. You're right that this doesn't work and the probability for tails is still $\frac12$.

By contrast, in the video you hear a croak from the general direction of the two frogs, so you only know that one of them is male, but not which one. The video does make a bit of a mistake in assuming that one male and two males would have been equally likely to give a single croak while you were listening. However, if you did somehow get the information that at least one of the frogs is male in a manner that doesn't distinguish between the possibilities of one male or two males, then indeed the probability of there being one male would be $\frac23$.

Comment: So if I was in the forest and I heard but did not see the croak it's $2/3$, but had I turned my head a few seconds earlier and also seen which croaked all of a sudden it's $1/2$? This doesn't make much sense to me, it seems as if real world objects can behave like quantum mechanics, just by observing you change another's odds?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, turning your head earlier doesn't change the probability. Also, surviving probability in the first case is $\frac{2}{3}$ only if male frog's croak probability when he sees you is $\frac{1}{2}$. Look at [grand_chat's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683796/168361).

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: No, you're talking about a single identifiable croak, and as I wrote that's not the assumption that leads to $\frac23$. It's $\frac23$ if you get precisely the information that at least one of the frogs is male. It's conceivable that you might get that information from croaking, e.g. if you listen long enough that you'd be sure to hear croaks if there's a male, but you don't know enough about the frequency of croaking to tell whether it's one or two males croaking. In that case turning your head and looking would allow you to identify both frogs correctly.

Comment: I can't think of any reasonable non-quantum process (with assumption of independence btw frogs) generating croaks that won't make MM more likely to produce a croak than MF: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683658/the-frog-puzzle/1683697#comment3436248_1683658 for example. Hearing $1$ croak from $2$ frogs is like hearing $0$ croaks from $1$ frog.

Comment: @A.S.: What's wrong with the process I proposed above? (By the way, the more fundamental incosistency to me seems that whatever process one imagines for the two frogs should also apply to the one frog, and would necessarily make it more likely that this frog is female since it wasn't heard croaking.)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little - I might have misunderstood the underlying process? It seems like the result is frequency independent since I am comparing odds of $MF:MM$ given a croak vs $F:M$ given no croaks and claiming they are equal. If you look at the linked comment, I address this inconsistency and the same result holds for male crocking or not once with some fixed probability in the time-frame of observation.

Comment: @A.S.: my suggestion was "if you listen long enough that you'd be sure to hear croaks if there's a male, but you don't know enough about the frequency of croaking to tell whether it's one or two males croaking" -- that would ensure that you definitely hear croaking for MF, MM and M but not for F, no?

Comment: Yes, but no matter how long you listen or what a frequency of croaking is, probability of $FM$ given $1$ croak is equal to probability of $F$ given $0$ croaks. And failing to see the *conclusion* you are making from the process described by the quote. What is it? I took it to mean as 2:1 odds of a female given the context. // Well, if you have MM and listen for the same period of time, you should probably hear two croaks rather than one. For $MF:MM = F:M$ given $1:0$ croaks

Comment: @A.S.: That's not what I meant. I meant that you listen for a long time and hear many croaks, and the time is long enough that you're sure that you'd have heard croaks if either one or two males were present; but you don't know enough about their frequency of croaking to tell whether it's one or two of them producing the many croaks.

Comment: I'm still not clear as to what the eventual conclusion/comparison/decision is. If you heard just one croak, you are indifferent between the group of two and the group of 1. If you heard more than one, you strictly prefer the group of one. Just focusing on the group of 2, you can't say anything for certain without knowing underlying probabilities/intensities, etc.

Comment: @A.S.: It seems we're talking past each other, and I can't see what's causing it. Perhaps let's just let it go :-)

Comment: I was specifically referring to "*It's $\frac 2 3$ if you get precisely the information that at least one of the frogs is male. It's conceivable that you might get that information from croaking*". I can't conceive of a process that yields exactly that information if we assume that croaks coming from males are i.i.d. processes or some weak dependencies.

Comment: It seems to me that the frogs are not MM or MF or anything but are rather "??" and once at least one identifies as male you are now left with "M?" but the "?" is still what its' always been, 50:50  male:female

Comment: @A.S.: I tried to describe such a process, and our communication about that attempt failed miserably. I don't know why. It's not important enough to me to keep trying to find out.