# Probability problem

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I created this problem based on the following probability riddle [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpwSGsb-rTs).

You're a king, and you were given two groups of people, and a certain information about them.

- First group has **2 people**. **One** of them is **100%** certain to be guilty of a crime. The other one is **50%** likely to be guilty and **50%** likely to be innocent, and you don't know which one is which.
- Second group is composed by only **1 person**. That person is **50%** likely to be guilty of a crime and **50%** likely to be innocent.

Now you need to imprison either the first group or the second group.

*By choosing the first group, what is the probability that you imprison an innocent person? What if you imprison the second group?*

My thought is that it wouldn't matter, in both cases is 50%, but according to the video it's not (I suggest checking it). Maybe you guys can shed some light on this.

Comment: A better question would be locking up one person in the first group, chosen at random from the two in the group.  Then the probability of locking up an innocent person is $25\%$.

Comment: @Henry Yes that would be a better question. I really wanted to discuss the video's calculations, a better explanation to them, and if they're correct at all. But thanks for the observation.

Comment: Given the accepted answer this question is incorrectly formulated. As formulated the correct answer should be 50% as @joriki pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose the first group, one has 0% chance of innocence, and another has 50%. So the average for that one is 25%.
The second group is just one person with a 50% chance, so that one is 50%.

Comment: So why in the video they say it's 67% chance? That's what I'd like to know... I recommend checking it since it's the root of my question.

Comment: But the question was to imprison either group one or group two. Imprisoning group one includes you imprison both the first and second person - the second person has 50% chance of innocence (which means that you have 50% risk of imprisoning an innocent person).

Answer (score 2):

Your analogy with the video is flawed. The situation you describe is not analogous to the situation described in the video. The video has been discussed at length on this site; see [The frog puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683658) and also [Basic probability : the frog riddle - what are the chances?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688332). Your result that the probability to imprison an innocent person is $50\%$ no matter which group you imprison is correct.