# A variant of the boy/girl paradox

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Some friends and I were arguing about the two following word problems, which are variants of the classic [boy/girl paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox).

(i) "Mrs.Smith lives in a world where the eldest child is always male. She has two children, one older and one younger (although you do not know which is which). What is the probability that they are both male?"

(ii) "Mrs.Smith has two children, one older and one younger (although you do not know which is which). The eldest child is male. What is the probability that they are both male?" You can assume that being the eldest child is independent of being male in this problem.

My answer to (i) was $\frac{1}{3}$ and to (ii) $\frac{1}{2}$. My friends believe the answer to both is $\frac{1}{2}$. In what follows, I make an assumption throughout that one child has to be (at least slightly) older than the other since this didn't seem to be a point of disagreement between us.
Here is my way of answering each question.

*Question (i)*

I make the background assumptions that there is always an eldest child and eldest $\implies$ male. Notice that the two background assumptions imply that at least one child in every pair is male. We can thus reformulate the problem as asking whether for the probability that both children are male given that at least one is male. Let $A = \text{"Both children are male."}$, $B = \text{"At least one child is male."}$. We wish to find $P(A|B)$. By Bayes's theorem,
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}.$$

If both children are male, clearly at least one child is male. Hence, $P(B|A) = 1$. Since our background assumptions imply at least one child in every pair is male (and imply nothing stronger than that), the possible sex distributions are $\{MM,MF,FM\}$, so $P(A) = \frac{1}{3}$ and $P(B) = 1$. Therefore,
$$P(A|B) = \frac{1 \cdot \frac{1}{3}}{1} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

*Question (ii)*

I make the background assumption that there is always an eldest child (who is not necessarily male in general). Let $A = \text{"Both children are male."}$, $B = \text{"The eldest child is male."}$. By Bayes's theorem,
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}.$$

If both children are male, then clearly the eldest child is male, so $P(B|A) = 1$. The possible sex distributions are $\{MM,MF,FM,FF\}$, so $P(A) = \frac{1}{4}$. Since being the eldest child is independent of being male, $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore,
$$P(A|B) = \frac{1 \cdot \frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Are these two arguments and their results correct?

EDIT: I have a follow-up question that came up in the comments. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpwSGsb-rTs). They say the probability that at least one of the two frogs on the left is female is $\frac{2}{3}$. But consider the following statement, seemingly analogous to (i).

(i') "Mrs.Smith lives in a world where a frog that croaks is always male. She has two frogs, one that croaks and one that doesn't (although you do not know which is which). What is the probability that they are not both male?"

Then by analogy with (i), you get that the probability that both are male is $\frac{1}{2}$, so the probability that not both are male is also $\frac{1}{2}$.

It seems to me that if you believe (i) is correct, you should also believe the frog video is incorrect and that the answer is actually $\frac{1}{2}$. What goes wrong here (if anything)?

Comment: A nitpick... the word "odds" is *not* a synonym for the word "probability."  If you want to talk about probabilities then only use the word probability.  They are related but decidedly different concepts with different meanings and different notations.  The probability of flipping a head on a fair coin is $\frac{1}{2}$.  The *odds* of doing so however are $1:1$.

Comment: For question (i), you say that the possible sex distributions are $\{MM,MF,FM\}$ and assume these are equally likely to occur.  Why do you assume that $MF$ is one of the possibilities (*assuming the notation stands for younger child's gender on left and older child's gender on right*)?  This directly contradicts your earlier assumption that the eldest child is always male.  There are only two possibilities here, not three.  Namely $\{FM, MM\}$.  Just because you can make conclusions from earlier hypotheses this doesn't make it so the earlier hypotheses suddenly disappear and become irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with your first comment and have edited my question accordingly. Your second comment gets at what I'm suspecting is my mistake. So suppose we agree that the answer to both (i) and (ii) is $\frac{1}{2}$. Then my follow-up question is as follows: In [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpwSGsb-rTs](this video), shouldn't the correct probability that one of the two frogs on the left is male be $\frac{1}{2}$ as well? I follow-up in a subsequent comment.

Comment: No.$~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: It seems you can reformulate the frog problem as follows: "Mrs.Smith lives in a world where a frog that croaks is always male. She has two frogs, one that croaks and one that doesn't (although you do not know which is which). What is the probability that they are not both male?" Then by analogy with (i), you get that the probability that both are male is $\frac{1}{2}$, so the probability that not both are male is also $\frac{1}{2}$. What goes wrong here?

Comment: First please explain how childbearing works in the world where the eldest child is always male. What is the mechanism that ensures this? How does the mechanism allow females to be born from later births? If a woman with one child becomes pregnant, what's the probability that the child conceived in this pregnancy is male? How does that work? How much do males outnumber females in that world?

Comment: Note that in the video we don't know that the _eldest_ frog on the left is male. We only know that _at least one_ of the frogs is male. It could be the case that the older frog is female and the younger frog is male, which you ruled out in case (i) in your question.

Comment: I don't see how some of these questions are relevant (in particular, "What is the mechanism that ensures this? How does the mechanism allow females to be born from later births?"). You can assume that the number of men and women is equal and that male and female births are independent, even though the eldest child is always male.

Comment: In the video we know that one of the frogs on the left croaks, hence is male, which is analogous to knowing that one of the children is the eldest, hence is male.

Comment: There however is a guarantee that among two children one will be eldest but there is not a guarantee that a frog will croak within a certain time frame.  Hearing a frog croak is not analogous to knowing all eldest children are male.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683658/179297